# TensorFlow MLP unhashable type 'list'

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

I'm trying to feed a MLP with an array. The input array contains 120 floats and the output contains 2.

```
sess.run(init)
# Training cycle
train = True
if train is True:
    for i in range(50):
        for letter in d1:
            #print(letter[0][0][0:5])
            letter[0][0][0:5] = sorted(letter[0][0][0:5], key=itemgetter(0))
            letter[0][0][5:10] = sorted(letter[0][0][5:10], key=itemgetter(0))
            #print(np.squeeze(np.asarray(d1[0])))
            result=[]
            for x in letter[0][0]:
                for y in x:
                    result.append(y)
            div = (result)

            xxx = [letter[0][1][0], int(not letter[0][1][0])]
            xxx = (xxx)
            print(result)

            #print(letter[1])
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: div, y: xxx})
```

When executing the last line it throws the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf.py", line 97, in <module>
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: div, y: xxx})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you had at the beginning of your code two placeholder `x` and `y`:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

---

The issue is that in your code, you use again the same name `x` and `y` for two variables:

```py
for x in letter[0][0]:
    for y in x:
        result.append(y)
```

This will erase the previous value of `x` and `y`.
Instead, you should use other names like:

```py
for ix in letter[0][0]:
    for iy in ix:
        result.append(iy)
```